# Natural Language Processing to Machine Learning

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, nlp, space, cpu-word

I'm new in Natural Language Processing but I've studied lot of techniques in Machine Learning, specially in Matlab. My big question is that when I work with texts (in Matlab), we have three problems for using ML algorithms:

1. The data space of the words is not numerical, for that, I can't use the algorithms directly. Do I need some transformation? I read about Kernel String, word embedding but I don't know how they resolve this problem.
2. The number of features is variable for each word, I mean, when we obtain the vectors, we could have the next and previous words + POS tagging of the actual word and not all of them have. Can we set this features to 0 for computing this in a matrix?. In general, I have problems to resolve the dependencies like grammar parsing in a vector.
3. Labels in a text are separated by sequences (sentence level). How we know in a vector the separation between sentences?

Comment: What algorithms are you talking about? Not all ML algorithms need numerical features. And what do you mean with "labels in a text"? Are you talking about sentence splitting?

Comment: Algorithms like CRF, SVM, Neural Nets... The labels for supervised learning for example in Name Entity Recognition

Comment: You can perfectly well train classifiers like SVM or NN with symbolic features – they're binarised, each word in the vocabulary is either present or not in a training instance. – Your last point still doesn't make any sense to me. The annotated labels in the training data aren't found in the text, but rather in the annotation layer.

Comment: Could you explain me what mean binarised?. My last question is about the vector of labels, for example in NER you have various sentences and each word is annotated by one class, but in this vector you don't know when a sentence ended.

Comment: I really don't know matlab, maybe it's not very straightforward to do NLP/text processing. However, there is heavy use of SVM, NN, CRF and many more algorithms in the NLP community, so you maybe just need to switch the tool/programming language. You should really post some code of what you tried and where you got stuck in order for someone to give you helpful advice.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways you can transform text to numerical values. 
I have mentioned two  common methods using the "Bag-of-words" assumption

Bag-of-words works like this:

Assume that you have three documents that look like:

Doc 1: the cat jumped over the lazy fox
Doc 2: machine learning is a subfield of artifical intelligence
Doc 3: that is a cat feeding machine

In this case, you have a vocabulary size (# of unique words) in the data corpus of 16, and you can store the index the words in a dictionary (python) or hashmap (java/c++) as:

1 : the

2 : cat

3 : jumped

...

In this case, you can represent the doc 1 (in the most simplistic dense way) as a vector of V length, and store the number of times each word appeared.

Doc 1: [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, ...]

Another thing you can do is to figure out the importance of each word to each document, and for that you can read more on Wikipedia about TF-IDF.

Comment: Thanks, but what about in NER? I need features like the POS tagging or the lemma and the previous/next of the word, how do I represent this features (question number 2)?

Comment: I think there are a couple of research papers explaining how to do that:

Try reading:  Wallach, H. Topic modeling: Beyond bag of words. In
Proceedings of the 23rd International Conference on
Machine Learning (2006).